# Solving PDE by separation of variables method

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I'm trying to solve $$u_x - 2u_y = u$$

with initial condition $u(x,0)=6e^{-3x}$. I begin by trying to find a solution of the form $$u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$$

substituting this into the PDE yields the relation $$\frac{-2X}{X-X'}=\frac{Y}{Y'}=\lambda$$

where $\lambda$ is a constant to be determined. The relation contains two ordinary differential equations $$(1)\enspace X\bigg(\frac{-\lambda-2}{-\lambda}\bigg)=X'$$ $$(2)\enspace Y'-\frac{Y}{\lambda}=0$$

The solutions are $$X(x)=e^{\alpha x},\enspace Y(y)=e^{\frac{y}{\lambda}}$$

where $\alpha = \frac{\lambda+2}{\lambda}$. How would one determine the constant $\lambda$ at this point? I tried substituting this solution into the initial condition, but it does not seem to be the way. Also, I have introduced $\lambda$ without first determining whether or not its explicitly positive or negative in this case, so the solution might be false.

Comment: Instead of messing around with SOV, why not just solve it directly using characteristics? The equation is linear constant coefficient, so it should be very easy.

Comment: That should be $X(x) = e^{-\alpha x}$, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there.  Putting your solutions together, and including an arbitrary normalization constant, you have obtained the result that
$$
u(x,y) = A \exp \left( - \frac{(\lambda + 2)x - y}{\lambda} \right).
$$
Now plug in $y = 0$ to this form and see if you can figure out the values of $A$ and $\lambda$ needed to yield $u(x,0) = 6 e^{-3x}$.